# Void as a str_replace() param in PHP 8

Tags: php, php-8

I'm trying to move my small project to PHP 8 and I'm struggling with an equivalent of `str_replace()` function.

```
public function renderView($view)
{
    $layoutContent = $this->layoutContent();
    $viewContent = $this->renderOnlyView($view);
    return str_replace('{{content}}', ($viewContent), strval($layoutContent));
}

protected function layoutContent()
{
    ob_start();
    include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/layouts/main.php";
    ob_get_clean();
}


protected function renderOnlyView($view)
{
    ob_start();
    include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/$view.php";
    ob_get_clean();
}
```

The problem is that in PHP 8 cannot use $view in `str_replace()` function and I'm getting: `Expected type 'array|string'. Found 'void'`

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: your `renderOnlyView` function is not returning anything, and you are adding that nothing (`void`) to the `str_replace`. What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: So I have a template.php and it contains a header, navbar, footer, and inside I've got a `{{content}}` string to be replaced with the value of the contact-template.php, home-page.php etc

Comment: The problem is that you're passing nothing to str_replace(), as @AdamBaranyai said.

Comment: Just to be clear, **the code as shown will never have done what you describe, in any PHP version**. The `str_replace` function is not being passed anything, because neither `layoutContent` nor `renderOnlyView` return a value. I'm voting to close as "needs debugging details", because if you have code that worked in PHP 7, it is not the code you have shown us. Possibly, this code has always been broken, and PHP 8 is just being more helpful at pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly the other parts of your code, this is only a guess by me, but try modifying your `renderOnlyView` and `layoutContent` functions, like this:

```
public function renderView($view)
{
    $layoutContent = $this->layoutContent();
    $viewContent = $this->renderOnlyView($view);
    return str_replace('{{content}}', $viewContent, $layoutContent);
}

protected function layoutContent()
{
    ob_start();
    include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/layouts/main.php";
    $out = ob_get_clean();

    return $out;
}

protected function renderOnlyView($view)
{
    ob_start();
    include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/$view.php";
    $out = ob_get_clean();

    return $out;
}
```

This should capture every `echo`-ed information from your `Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/$view.php"` and `Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/layouts/main.php"` files respectively, and return it as a string to the caller scope.

Comment: `public function renderView($view)  
    {  
        $layoutContent = $this->layoutContent();  
        include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/$view.php";  
    }
  
  
    protected function layoutContent()  
    {  
        include_once Application::$ROOT_DIR."/views/layouts/main.php";  
    }  

`

Until my functions are looking like this and renderOnlyView is not used it works, but returning {{content}} in the middle of the file. Your changes don't do anything. Do you need to see any exact part of the code?

Comment: Adam Baranyai functions look good. I don't believe his changes don't do anything. Do you still get Expected type 'array|string'. Found 'void' ?

Comment: Those two includes are most likely echoing output, which you are trying to capture in the current version of your code in the question, then throw it away. My modifications should capture those outputs, and pass them forward. I made another modification to your first function, try that out too, and tell me if it works now. (I am not fammiliar with wrapping a variable in parantheses, but yet again, I am working in PHP 7 not 8, so maybe that's something new)

Comment: Also, if the error disappears because of my changes, yet you are still seeing blank screens, it means, that you are not echoing out the output of `renderView` function anywhere. In that case, change the `return str_replace(...)` to `echo str_replace(...)`

Answer (score -1):

If you set `strict_types = 1` then you must pass the arguments as array so

```
public function renderView($view)
{
    $layoutContent = $this->layoutContent();
    $viewContent = $this->renderOnlyView($view);
    return str_replace(['{{content}}'], [$viewContent], strval($layoutContent));
}
```

You can read it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56944)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting a blank page, please check my comment above, there's a code that is working but not replacing the {{content}}

Comment: Also works the same way if I'll return the include_once for `layoutContent()` and `renderOnlyView($view)`, but I still have got the {{content}} string to be replaced there

Comment: This answer is simply wrong: str_replace takes either string or array arguments

Comment: Can you take a look at this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56944

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai That says the same thing as me: it takes either a string or an array. The OP was attempting to pass a string, which is perfectly valid, but had a bug elsewhere meaning they were passing null. Wrapping the null in an array won't solve the problem, although it might hide it if PHP doesn't check the types inside the array.